# Bind data with list,string fields to the grid view in winforms c# through interface

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to bind data to grid. My class as follows.

```
     public class Dependency
     {
         public string issueID { get; set; }
         public string jirastatus { get; set; }
         public int dependencyFound { get; set; }
         public List<string> depends { get; set; }
         public List<string> linked_issues { get; set; }
       }
```

I am trying to bind the data through the wizard or UI. 
[image]

Here the list type fields are not appearing. Through UI is it not possible? 
I dont have idea about how to bind through the code. Can any once give me any link or solution for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the parent-child relation (collection associations) you populate one gridview with parent level data. When user clicks on one of the record fetch and show the corresponding child data in separate grid(s), when it is a list type. Otherwise you may need to consider using thir-party grid controls which support the nested grid display.